# Symfony2: using assetic:dump result in hundreds of css being included in dev pages

Tags: symfony, assetic

I'm creating a website using symfony2,  on my local machine i want to try to test the "production" mode, so i'm dumping my css files using

```
 php app/console assetic:dump
```

in  `localhost/backend/channel` now i got this CSS links generated

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/51c56cc.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/f2e689f.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/f639ea7.css"/>
```

but now if I got back to dev mode  `localhost/app_dev.php/backend/channel` now i got hundreds (247 to be precise) of css requests (where before the assetic:dump in dev mode, i used to have only 10 requests)

my assetic in config_dev.yml

```
assetic:
   use_controller: true
```

and in config.yml

```
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [MVMSBackendBundle]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
    assets:
        jquery:
            inputs:
                - 'js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'
        ie_compat:
            inputs:
                - 'js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js'
        responsive:
            inputs:
                - 'js/bootstrap.min.js'
```

am I doing something wrong ? is it a bug of assetics dumps ? how do I "undo" it ?

Comment: can you show us your assetic.yml config file

Comment: @elkorchianas , I've edited my answer to add these information,  also should i precise i'm using the FOSRestBundle ?

Comment: why did you comment yui compressor? I think this is the probleme

Comment: i didn't commented it, that's the default config file, also i really hope symfony2 should works correclly if i dont have an optional .jar that require to install the JVM  :/

Comment: there is another option you can use UglifyJS and UglifyCSS to minfy your assetic files see this http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/uglifyjs.html

Comment: still here i don't understand the root problem, why does dumping the assetic generate so much more css files than not doing it (making things worse),  i mean ,  if i have to use a compressor, then assetic should not let me dump without getting one configured , no ?

Answer (score 0):

it seems I should use

```
 php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

so that it dumps only for the prod environment

to "undo" the dump of dev assetics , once simply has to clear the cache and delete the dumped file.

I'm still not clear on why it has generated that many CSS links though.